# Make Fix Size of Hex Number Python

Tags: python, hex

I want make my hex number have 2 bytes size. How I can do it? Example,if in C we can make `%02f`. How I make it in Python2.7?
Thankyou

Comment: what is a "hexa number"? could you maybe provide example input and expected output?

Comment: sorry, it solved by my self. I mean hex number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to use like this : `"{0:03x}".format(number)` and works

Answer (score 1):

You can format it in a similar way. Just use `"%02x" % (the_number,)`

Answer (score 0):

In python the use of hexadecimals is not that common. It is therefore typically represented as either a string or int, ie:

```py
print type(0x50),0x50
#returns <type 'int'> 80
print type(hex(80),hex(80)
#returns <type 'str'>, '0x50'
```

Knowing this you, could exploit this property by doing something along the line of:

```py
myhex_int=0x5 #integer with value 5
myhex_str='%02d'%myhex_int #string '05',use '0x02d' if you prefer this
#to return it to an integer again:
myhex2=int(myhex_str,16) #set base to 16 
#integer with value 5
```